# Sculpting with textures - rotate/scale sculpt preview before apply?

Tags: sculpting

Anybody knows how to apply a texture while sculpting that way ?

it looks like a stencil but easier to use

@ 13:35

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJtNfDKHzmo&ab_channel=GrantAbbitt

thanks for your help

Comment: It doesn't say how to in that video?

Comment: yep, found out after a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is @ 5:03
it's the anchor brush